# Rename a string from app.js to app.min.js in bash

Tags: regex, bash

What's the quickest way to take a string like "app.js" and rename it to "app.min.js" in bash?

I was hoping for an awk regex or something where I can do:

```
s/(.*?)\.js/$1.min.js/
```

Comment: What's wrong with the `sed` command in your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way:

```
string=app.js
string=${string/./.min.}
```

Comment: There a way to get it to work with filename like this? app.foo.js so it becomes app.foo.min.js

Comment: When I use your example with string=app.foo.js I get app.min.foo.js -- I want app.foo.min.js (always just before extension)

Comment: Try: `string=${string%.js}.min.js`